# Auto sum for horizontal numeric boxes not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use auto sum functionality for 3 horizontal boxes, neither auto sum is working and not sure what has gone wrong with readonly property also, even that is not working for me.

below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#t3").prop('readOnly',true);
    var sum=0;
    for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        $("#t"+i).keyup(function(){
            sum=sum+parseInt(this.val());
        });
    }
    $("#t3").val(sum);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="t1"><input type="text"></td>
        <td id="t2"><input type="text"></td>
        <td id="t3"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event on the `input`'s not on the `td`'s:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#t3  input").prop('readOnly',true);
    var sum=0;
    for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        $("#t"+i + " input").keyup(function(){
            sum=sum+parseInt(this.val());
        });
    }
    $("#t3 input").val(sum);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding code inside a `for` loop is not a good thing, write code commonly.

Try,

```
$('#t1,#t2 input').keyup(function(){
    var val1 = parseInt($('#t1 input').val(),10);
    var val2 = parseInt($('#t2 input').val(),10)
    var res = (isNaN(val1)?0:val1) + (isNaN(val2)?0:val2)
    $('#t3 input').val(res);
});
```

REMOVE THIS CROSSED PART FROM YOUR CODE:

```
    var sum=0;
    for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        $("#t"+i).keyup(function(){
            sum=sum+parseInt(this.val());
        });
    }
    $("#t3").val(sum);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y6E5z/2/)

---

Update for your new requirement,

```
$('tr td:nth-child(3) input').prop('disabled', true);

$('tr td input:not(:disabled)').keyup(function () {

    var res = $(this).closest('tr').find("input:not(:disabled)").map(function(){
        return isNaN(parseInt(this.value, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(this.value, 10);
    }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b
    }, 0);

    $(this).closest('tr').find("input:disabled").val(res);

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y6E5z/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I checked the demo..however I have several rows like this, so I want to use them in loop..will this way work in loop also?

Comment: @user2866314 : Yes, it worked, But my requirement is to use this in loop..Below is what I am using



        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#t3").find("input").prop('readOnly', true);
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
                {
                    $("#t"+i).find("input").keyup(function() {
                        sum = sum + parseInt($(this).find("input").val(),10);
                    });
                }
                $("#t3").find("input").val(isNaN(sum)?0:sum);
            });
        </script>